# Tabbar buttons order changed after go to other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbar

I have 2 buttons in my tabbar, programmatically added. But the order changed after navigating to another placeholder within the view.

When I open the app:
[image]
When I go to the movies tab:
[image]

The code:

```
self.searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(toggleSearchBar)];

UIImage* meetupButtonIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meetup_logo_icon"];
UIImage* meetupButtonIconHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meetup_logo_icon_highlighted"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
UIButton *meetupUIButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[meetupUIButton setBackgroundImage:meetupButtonIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[meetupUIButton setBackgroundImage:meetupButtonIconHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[meetupUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMeetup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *meetupIcon =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:meetupUIButton];
self.meetupButton = meetupIcon;

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_meetupButton, _searchButton, nil]];
```

The strange thing is I need to add the buttons in the wrong order in the array: _meetupButton, _searchButton and looks like it change to the right order. My question how to force the images to be always in the same order.

Comment: Are you setting the buttons once or every time a placeholder view is changed ? The documentation of `rightBarButtonItems` defines the buttons order in the way that matches your code and the first screenshot (on a left-to-right UI), if you set the rightBarButtonItems anywhere else with a different order you can expect the navigation bar to update accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something maybe goes wrong. However to get it working,  `leftBarButtonItems` of `navigationItem` can be ordered with sequence of `Array` which you assign and `rightBarButtonItems` of `navigationItem`  can be ordered with inverted sequence of `Array` which you assign.

Maybe you can give it a try!